# flex 3: passing values to function using alert window

Tags: apache-flex, alert

I have a function that checks for something when the user clicks a button.  if that something is found, an alert comes up saying that it has been found and asks them if they would like to allow this to happen, or undo the action that caused the something to be found.  the code looks like this:

```
Alert.show(thisString1, "Conflict: Multiple Projects", 3, this, conflictAnswer);
```

upon pressing "Yes" or "No", the conflictAnswer function will be called... it looks like this:

```
private function conflictAnswer(event:CloseEvent):void
{
    if (event.detail == Alert.YES)
    {
        Alert.show(
    }
}
```

My question is this, how would i pass some variables that are held in the function that displays the Alert?  i tried something like this:

```
Alert.show(thisString1, "Conflict: Multiple Projects", 3, this, conflictAnswer(Event, var1, var2));


private function conflictAnswer(event:CloseEvent, varA, varB):void
{
    if (event.detail == Alert.YES)
    {

    }
}
```

but it didn't work.

Can anybody help me out?

Thanks
Brds

***EDIT***
After reading the first respond, i've come up with this:

```
answers[0] = cPositions[i][0];
answers[1] = cPositions[i][1];
var anAlert:Alert = Alert.show(thisString1, "Conflict: Multiple Projects", 3, this, conflictAnswer);
anAlert.data = {answers:Array};
```

and then the conflictAnswer function looks like this:

```
private function conflictAnswer(event:CloseEvent):void
{
    var projectID:Number = event.currentTarget.answers[0];
    var positionID:Number = event.currentTarget.answers[1];
    if (event.detail == Alert.YES)
    {
        Alert.show(String(projectID + " | " + positionID));
    }
}
```

but this isn't working... any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

`Alert.show()` returns an alert instance which has `data` field where you can set your data:

```
var anAlert:Alert = Alert.show(thisString1, "Conflict: Multiple Projects", 3, this, conflictAnswer);
anAlert.data = {var1:var1, var2:var2};
```

Then in event handler you can get your data object:

```
var myData:Object = event.currentTarget.data;
var var1:Object = myData.var1;
var var2:Object = myData.var2;
```

For your code it will look like the following:

```
answers[0] = cPositions[i][0];
answers[1] = cPositions[i][1];
var anAlert:Alert = Alert.show(thisString1, "Conflict: Multiple Projects", 3, this, conflictAnswer);
anAlert.data = {answers:answers};
```

and then:

```
private function conflictAnswer(event:CloseEvent):void
{
    var projectID:Number = event.currentTarget.data.answers[0];
    var positionID:Number = event.currentTarget.data.answers[1];
    if (event.detail == Alert.YES)
    {
        Alert.show(String(projectID + " | " + positionID));
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not really sure how to use what you've responded with to help me out.  I understand what you're saying, i'm just not sure how to make it happen.  I have an Alert.show call... can i set the data within that?  The Alert.show is displayed in the original question.

Comment: I've added an extra line to my answer to clarify what I mean saying "Alert.show() returns an alert instance" :)

Comment: I have a couple more questions... i've added them below then EDIT piece of the original post

Comment: I'm getting an Alert window of NaN | NaN from the conflictAnswer... but if do a Alert.show(typeof(answers[0])); in the first part, i get a return of "Number"... any thoughts?